Java android app not working properly on some devices
The app is basic it has a button on mainactivity.java which open mycustomcamera.java from where we can capture photos and videos. Captured photos and videos will be displayed to mainactivity.java 's recyclerview. Mainactivity.java has upload button by pressing it upload capture media to server
The problem is it is not working perfectly on Samsung s9(android 10) and Samsung as53(android 14)
On other devices it is working perfectly like Samsung m35(android 14), Motorola G9(android 11), Motorola E7 power(android 10).
Please help

Nobody knows what "is not working perfectly" means to you. Please edit your question to include a [mcve], including a detailed explanation of your expected results and what you are seeing on the troublesome devices.

First of all thank you very much for your time, by "not working properly" I meant on a53 it is showing items twice(duplicate) instead of showing them one

Without a [mcve], nobody will be able to assist you with your issue.

I have sent you an email. I hope that I have mentioned things clearly there. Please check and help

That is very inappropriate.

Really Sorry for that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79303229/my-android-app-not-working-on-samsung-a53-but-working-on-samsung-m35
