My android app not working on Samsung A53 but working on Samsung M35
Let me start from the beginning so nothing gets missed. I have started in September 2024 to create an android app in which there will 2 switches named "Capture on/off" and "Auto upload on/off" and 3 buttons named "Configure", "Select" and "Upload". There is also a recyclerview.
The was suppose to be simple. It is to be like this open app, press Configure button enters details and save them(this is to be done once only just after installing the app). Now when we turn on Capture on/off switch, a service is started and keeps running what this service do is when we takes picture by our phone's camera app the service add the path(location of the picture) to the app 's local sql database and the other Auto upload on/off switch immediately upload the picture to our server(this also use service)
Now to make user that service is running I have created a notification which stays when service is running.
The idea for this app was open app turn either of switch depending upon your internet speed and upload pictures. I have used database in case of upload fails we still have our picture in app database and once pictures are uploaded pictures path get removed. Also, picture path which are in database will be displayed in recyclerview.
This working on my Samsung M35(android 14) but not on Samsung A53(android 14).
To solve this issue, I tried to change my approach now instead of having a service listening for a picture captured now I added mycustomcamera.java from which pictures can be taken. But this approach is also not working on A53.
I am attaching screen recording link for your reference of my first approach(service one).
Screen Recording Download Link
we.tl/t-eyAM1IntqN
Please help

There is no code. Add a [MRE] to the question.
